# Вывести изображение из БД в PHP Коде

Tags: php

прошу помощи у Вас. Я не силён в php, пока только учусь. Возникла проблема вывести на другом месте сайта изображение, по примеру аналогичного файла. Но там Тёмный лес для меня.
Ниже пример кода от куда нужно взять данные, данные я так понял выводятся при помощи  foreach.
Данные что отвечают за получение

```
<div class="view-article-rand-image" ><img class="image-autofocus" src="<?php echo Exists($config["media"]["big_image_blog"],$value["blog_articles_image"],$config["media"]["no_image"]); ?>" /></div>
```

полный код

```
<div class="blog-view-article-rand" >   
  <div class="row" >
  <?php
  
    foreach ($data["article_rand"]["all"] as $key => $value) {
      ?>
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-6" >
      <div class="all-full-article">
        <a href="<?php echo $Blog->aliasArticle($value); ?>"  >
         <div class="view-article-rand-image" ><img class="image-autofocus" src="<?php echo Exists($config["media"]["big_image_blog"],$value["blog_articles_image"],$config["media"]["no_image"]); ?>" /></div>
         <div class="article-date-info">
         <span class="article-item-cat-name" ><?php echo $ULang->t( $value["blog_category_name"] , [ "table"=>"uni_blog_category", "field"=>"blog_category_name" ] ); ?></span>
         <p><?php echo $ULang->t( $value["blog_articles_title"], [ "table"=>"uni_blog_articles", "field"=>"blog_articles_title" ] ); ?></p>
        </a>
        <span><i class="la la-clock"></i> <?php echo datetime_format($value["blog_articles_date_add"], false); ?> <i class="la la-eye ml5ib"></i> <?php echo $value["blog_articles_count_view"]; ?></span>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      <?php
    }
  
  ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Код куда нужно вывести эти данные ниже

```
<div class="row mt30" >
        <div class="col-lg-9" >
            <div class="bg-container" >
                
              -- разместить в это место вывод изображение --
              
               <div class="blog-view-text-content" >
                 <?php echo $ULang->t( urldecode($data["article"]["blog_articles_text"]), [ "table"=>"uni_blog_articles", "field"=>"blog_articles_text" ] ); ?>
               </div>

               <h4 class="mb30 mt30" > <strong> <?php echo $ULang->t("Комментарии"); ?> </strong> </h4>
               
               <?php if($_SESSION['profile']['id']){ ?>
                 <div class="module-comments-form-otvet mb25" >
                   <form class="module-comments-form" >
                   <textarea name="text" placeholder="<?php echo $ULang->t("Ваш комментарий ..."); ?>" ></textarea>
                     <button class="module-comments-form-send" ><i class="las la-arrow-right"></i></button>
                     <input type="hidden" name="id_article" value="<?php echo $data["article"]["blog_articles_id"]; ?>" >
                   </form>
                 </div>
               <?php }else{ ?>
                 <div class="alert alert-primary mb25" role="alert">
                  <?php echo $ULang->t("Добавлять комментарии могут только авторизованные пользователи!"); ?>
                 </div>                    
               <?php } ?>


               <div class="module-comments" >
                  
                  <noindex>
                  <?php
                  echo $Blog->outComments(0, $Blog->getComments($data["article"]["blog_articles_id"]));
                  ?>
                  </noindex>
                  
               </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3" >
            <?php include $config["basePath"] . "/templates/blog_view_sidebar.tpl"; ?>
        </div>
    </div>

   <?php echo $Banners->out( ["position_name"=>"blog_view_bottom", "current_id_cat"=>$data["article"]["blog_articles_id_cat"], "categories"=>$getCategoryBlog] ); ?>
      
   <div class="mt50" ></div>


</div>
```

если просто Вставить
Получаем только ["no_image"] изображение , а само изображение не выводится .
Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё решил сам !

```
 <div class="row mt30" >
        <div class="col-lg-9" >
            <div class="bg-container" >
            <?php
           if($data["article_rand"]["count"]){
           foreach ($data["article_rand"]["all"] as $key => $value) {
            ?>
           <div class="view-article-rand-image-big" style="background-image: url(<?php echo Exists($config["media"]["big_image_blog"],$value["blog_articles_image"],$config["media"]["no_image"]); ?>);" ></div>
               <div class="blog-view-text-content" >
                 <?php echo $ULang->t( urldecode($data["article"]["blog_articles_text"]), [ "table"=>"uni_blog_articles", "field"=>"blog_articles_text" ] ); ?>
               </div>

               <h4 class="mb30 mt30" > <strong> <?php echo $ULang->t("Комментарии"); ?> </strong> </h4>
               
               <?php if($_SESSION['profile']['id']){ ?>
                 <div class="module-comments-form-otvet mb25" >
                   <form class="module-comments-form" >
                   <textarea name="text" placeholder="<?php echo $ULang->t("Ваш комментарий ..."); ?>" ></textarea>
                     <button class="module-comments-form-send" ><i class="las la-arrow-right"></i></button>
                     <input type="hidden" name="id_article" value="<?php echo $data["article"]["blog_articles_id"]; ?>" >
                   </form>
                 </div>
               <?php }else{ ?>
                 <div class="alert alert-primary mb25" role="alert">
                  <?php echo $ULang->t("Добавлять комментарии могут только авторизованные пользователи!"); ?>
                 </div>                    
               <?php } ?>


               <div class="module-comments" >
                  
                  <noindex>
                  <?php
                  echo $Blog->outComments(0, $Blog->getComments($data["article"]["blog_articles_id"]));
                  ?>
                  </noindex>
                  
               </div>
               <?php
              }
            }
           ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3" >
            <?php include $config["basePath"] . "/templates/blog_view_sidebar.tpl"; ?>
        </div>
    </div>

   <?php echo $Banners->out( ["position_name"=>"blog_view_bottom", "current_id_cat"=>$data["article"]["blog_articles_id_cat"], "categories"=>$getCategoryBlog] ); ?>
      
   <div class="mt50" ></div>


</div>
```

Comment: Если Вы нашли ответ на свой вопрос, рекомендую пометить его как верный, чтобы закрыть данный вопрос (нажать на галочку слева от текста)